# Unable to serialize IDictionary<string,obj> in ASP.Net Core 3.0 in F#

Tags: serialization, f#, asp.net-core-3.0

When serializing a dictionary of (string, obj) with the default JSON serialization in ASP.Net Core 3.0 the following error was occurring:

unable to cast object of type 'system.szarrayenumerator' to type 'system.collections.idictionaryenumerator'.

Answer (score 2):

Was able resolve the issue by switching back to Newtonsoft for serialization via the nuget package: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson: 3.0.0

Comment: Yeah, the new JSON serialization in .NET Core 3.0 does not seem to be quite ready yet, at least not for F#.